# Should I start deleting signatures?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The faq states that signatures are unnecessary, and I've asked once nicely for one to be removed but no such luck yet. I can now edit posts, should I use this power to remove signatures? I'm thinking of ones such as this:
  [Ways to load OS VectorMap data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/764/ways-to-load-os-vectormap-data/801#801)

Which in my mind goes against the spirit of separating out the content of the answer from the person's user page where they provide context on themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that signatures are not appropriate for this site.

I think it's fine for high-rep users to edit posts, with good descriptions in the changelog of what they edited.

In cases like this, you would also be well-served adding a comment to the answer, with a polite note about signatures not being appropriate.  A large part of this site, especially in the early days, will be training GIS folks used to BBS-style resources how the Q&A format works.

P.S. That user went back and removed all their existing sigs in response to a comment.

Comment: Yeah, doing this will cause edit wars depending on the personality of the person being edited (or doing the editing for that matter). Doesn't seem to matter if it's nicely-worded or not, some people just don't get the "my question doesn't really belong to me" idea of StackExchange.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I meant that they went back and removed their existing sigs.  It worked well in this case :)  I can see where problems could show up in the future, but right now I think most cases are attributable to lack of experience...

Answer (score 4):

Yes I did re-edit all posts and removed them. BBS-Style resources is new to me.
@JasonBirch thanks for the kindly worded comment to remove them.

A lesson learned, a lesson gained.

We are all here to help others.